# mousedown and mouseup triggered on touch devices

Tags: javascript, events, touch, mousedown, mouseup

Just curious about the purpose of [mousedown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousedown) and [mouseup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseup) events since they are triggered also on touch devices.
I thought that [mousedown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousedown) and [touchstart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchstart) are mutually exclusive (the former working on desktop while the latter on touch devices) and the same for [mouseup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseup) and [touchend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchend), but it seems this is not the case. A complete touch event triggers all the above events: tested on safari and chrome. Thus to differentiate between a click (mouse) event and a click (touch) event I need to use some kind of function that tells me if this is a touch device or not:

```
    function isTouchDevice() {
        return 'ontouchstart' in window        // works on most browsers
            || navigator.maxTouchPoints;       // works on IE10/11 and Surface
    }

    myElem.addEventListener("mousedown", () => {
        if (isTouchDevice()) return;
        // do something
    }, false);

    myElem.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
        if (isTouchDevice()) return;
        // do something
    }, false);

    myElem.addEventListener("touchstart", () => {
        // do something
    }, false);

    myElem.addEventListener("touchend", () => {
        // do something
    }, false);
```

Do I really need to check if a device is touch or not to discriminate between mouse clicks and touch clicks?

Answer (score 3):

No, you don't and probably shouldn't attempt to test if the device is a touch screen or not. If you wish to stop the other events from triggering, you can use the preventDefault method.

```
myElem.addEventListener("touchstart", (event) => {
   event.preventDefault(); 
   // do something
}, false);
```

If you want more in-depth information, you should read this article: [Touch and Mouse](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touchandmouse/)